# Xcode 10 Removing lstdc++

Tags: ios, xcode, llvm, libc++

`lstdc++` is removed from Xcode 10 so I removed this lib from `"Link Binary With Libraries"` and I added libc++.tbd but I got something like that in linker

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      __GLOBAL__sub_I_BVMDOfflineMapMerge.cpp in BaiduMapAPI_Map(BVMDOfflineMapMerge.o)
  "std::string::assign(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      _baidu_framework::HandleBasemapMerge(_baidu_vi::CVString const&, _baidu_vi::CVString const&, _baidu_vi::CVString const&, char const*) in BaiduMapAPI_Map(BVMDOfflineMapMerge.o)
  "std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage", referenced from:
      _baidu_framework::HandleBasemapMerge(_baidu_vi::CVString const&, _baidu_vi::CVString const&, _baidu_vi::CVString const&, char const*) in BaiduMapAPI_Map(BVMDOfflineMapMerge.o)
  "std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<unsigned long>(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _baidu_framework::CBVDCVersion::Save() in BaiduMapAPI_Map(BVDEDataCfg.o)
```

I assue its problem with c++ lib.

Answer (score -1):

maybe ,sdk need update

BaiduMap maybe depend old lib